# NoSuchMethodError when trying to create a WebClient on Glassfish

Tags: maven, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x, htmlunit, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to create a `HtmlUnit WebClient` in order to parse an Ember app webpage inside a Java EE `Servlet filter` on a `Glassfish` server.

**servlet code:**

```
  final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); // causes error
  HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(originalUrl);
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.29</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>enunciate.xml</configFile>
                <enunciateArtifactId/>
                <enunciateArtifactId/>
                <moduleName/>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceExcludes>**/web.xml</warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>enunciate-rt</artifactId>
        <version>1.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paymill</groupId>
        <artifactId>paymill-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.3m</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev209-1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codemonkey.simplejavamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BrowserCompatSpecFactory.create(Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)Lorg/apache/http/cookie/CookieSpec;
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager.<init>(CookieManager.java:54)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:136)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:199)
```

Comment: Looks like a conflict in http client versions. You are trying to use (add as a dependency) 4.4. The Google Http client depends on [`<project.httpclient.version>4.0.1</project.httpclient.version>`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.pom)

Comment: You can disregard the org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4 from the deps list, the error appears even without it.

Comment: Just removed the com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.19.0. Same error. So that is not the issue. What is interfering with the HtmlUnit dependency ?

Comment: Did you try and remove them both? You can look at the [htmlunit pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.15/htmlunit-2.15.pom). It uses 4.3.3. I'm not really an HttpClient user, so I don't really know if there's any big difference. But normally when I see NoSuhMethodError it's 90 percent of the time a depedency versioning conflict. That's my best guess

Comment: Even `google-api-client` is dependent on HttpClient 4.0.1. You should try and do some maven eclusions with the dependencies, so all of them are just depending on one version.

Comment: Try the declare the htmlunit last and add a `<scope>test</scope>` to it, if its just used for testing.

Comment: Just removed all google related deps and the httpclient. Still nothing. Can't add the htmlunit as a test, it's not used for testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70580/discussion-between-andrew-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently moving the `HtmlUnit` dependency to the bottom of the dependencies list fixed the issue. Like peeskillet mentioned, this isn't a complete fix, as we still don't know what caused the issue in the first place, but it works as a first solution. Please do answer if you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but html unit is not the solution. I put the httpclient.jar to the top so the problem solved.